# Abandoned cart emails are not sending

Tags: promotions, enterprise-1.14, email-translation, email-reminders

looking for some advanced help here.

I am working with abandoned cart emails and I can not get the emails to send on command (by using the admin>run now or via command line: "php cron.php"

Customers have been matched up - so I am assuming that its not my rules. Once email has been sent after I set active dates. Then I set the repeat schedule to 1,2,3,...19,20, but nothing is being re-sent.

Other email transactions send out just fine.

Looking for advice on where and what to look for.

Comment: My advice is to look into your conditions, recently i had the same problem, I set the conditions and then it worked out for me

Comment: don't you want to use some extensions ?

Comment: The abandoned cart is a magento EE option. No need for an extension. I want the core functionality to work correctly.

Comment: <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2zJTce25eQaM19ESS1rV3d6V28/view?usp=sharing" width="100" height="100">
It would appear that the conditions should work - they are for the most basic of items - all our items are over $15.00.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!!
The Magento Core only allows for each abandoned email rule to only send out one email.

The repeat schedule should work - not in my case - I just created a new rule and kept the same conditions as the rule before and then ran now -- Email sent and now I can start working on styling!